# Recommend a good geometry textbook for me.

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I need a good geometry textbook that is suitable for beginners (but not too elementary), I mean the Olympiad level books that emphasizes on proofs and constructions, with a lot of theorems on triangles and circles.

Comment: I'm a huge fan of Geometry in Figures by Arseniy Akopyan but I'm not sure if it's suitable for everyone. A lot of IMO participant from my country love it as well.

Comment: I need one that emphasizes on Constructions

Comment: What languages would be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Prasolov.V.V. Geometric problems. (In Russian). I think it's the best.

Akopyan. A.V. Geometry in pictures.